# The css function does not work well in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Here are my codes:

```
var topPix = $('#cc').css('top');
var leftPix = $('#cc').css('left');  
$('#testFrame').css('top', topPix).css('left', leftPix);
```

And I give some styles to the 'testFrame', like 'position: absolute;' and so on.

It works well, however, I want to set 5px more to the 'top' property. And then I write the following code:

```
 $('#testFrame').css('top', topPix+'+=5px').css('left', leftPix);
```

or:

```
 $('#testFrame').css('top', topPix+'+=5').css('left', leftPix);
```

It does not work, besides, the value of 'top' looks like to minus an center pixel.
I do this in IE8.
I want to know why this would happen?
There are many solutions to the problem, like setting a margin or padding property.

Comment: a) Please format the code in your question properly. b) css works fine in jQuery. it's been tested by millions of users so odds are it's something you're not doing correctly. and c) what does "not work" mean? you need to provide more detail and a live example is useful for us to help you.

Comment: Assuming the value of `topPix` is `10`, then `topPix + '+=5'` will result in the string `"10+=5"`. Don't you want to perform arithmetic addition (`x + y`) instead of string concatenation?

Answer (score 3):

If you examined the value of topPix, you'd find that it was something like `"10px"` so adding `"+=5px"` to it results in `"10px+=5px"` which isn't a valid CSS value or anything that `.css()` supports.

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jtJ44/

If you do `parseInt(topPix, 10)`, it will convert it to a number which you can then add 5 to and then add "px" to it.

```
$('#testFrame').css("top", (parseInt(topPix, 10) + 5) + "px");
```

Or, you could use a special feature of the `.css()` method to use the `+=` operator and do this:

```
$('#testFrame').css("top", topPix).css("top", "+=5");
```

The `+=` special operator for `.css()` doesn't work like you were trying to use it.  You apply it only to the current value.  You can't combine it with some other value without first making that other value the current value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me an answer, I hava solve the problem using 'margin' instead of adding an certain pixel to the property 'top'.

Comment: @HaleDeng - since you are relatively new to StackOverflow, do you realize that if your question is answered, you are supposed to select one of the answers as the best answer by clicking the checkmark below the arrows to the left or each answer?  This tells other viewers which answer you thought was the best one, rewards the person who provided that answer and gives you a few reputation points for following through on your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
topPix+'+=5'
```

This will be evaluated as a string, not a number. Calculate the value into a variable and then set that variable in the .css function.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't do math, so in `.css('top', topPix+'+=5')` second parameter should be number of pixels, i.e. `.css('top', (topPix + 5) + 'px')`

Comment: This won't work because topPix is something like `10px` so your addition makes it `10px5px` which isn't a valid value for .css().  See my answer for details.

Comment: Just do a parseInt(topPix) to get the numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var position = $('#cc').position();
var topPix = position.top;
var leftPix = position.left;

$('#testFrame').css({
 top: parseInt(topPix) + 5,
 left: leftPix
});
```